# Помогите решить задачу Linux

Tags: linux, консоль

Выполните действия, перечисленные ниже, и в качестве ответа на задание введите правильную последовательность команд, разделяя их &&. Действия должны выполняться в контексте рута.

Сменить user1 оболочку на /bin/rbash.
Добавить user2 в группу sudo.
Удалить пользователя user3.

Мой ответ: **sudo chsh -s /bin/rbash user1 && sudo useradd -G sudo user2 && sudo userdel user3** система не принимает

Comment: А если убрать все sudo?

Comment: К сожалению, Действия должны выполняться в контексте рута

Comment: Это крайне не рекомендуется (большинству пользователей), но я частенько вызываю один раз `sudo bash` ... (а если по делу, то посмотрите на ключик **-c** для sh)

Comment: `- А если убрать все sudo? ... -К сожалению, Действия должны выполняться в контексте рута` -- наоборот,  `sudo` как раз подразумевает работу из **контекста пользователя**, где ты от пользователя запускаешь программу/ы для работы которой нужны права суперпользователя. **Контекст рута** подразумевает что ты сразу запускаешь программу/ы от рута(root). Визуально контекст выполнения обычно выражают начальным символом: `$ ` - от юзера, `# ` - от рута. В целом будет выглядеть так: `# chsh -s /bin/rbash user1 && usermod -aG sudo user2 && userdel user3`,  `useradd` для добавление в группу не подходит.

Comment: Спасибо, chsh -s /bin/rbash user1 && usermod -aG sudo user2 && userdel user3 - правильное решение.